# How to extract specific data from json with multiple nodes?

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

1. Using java with selenium
2. I have captured full json in my code
3. IN my json there are two nodes "Service1" and "Service2"
4. My requirement is to fetch the details of "Services1" node -->data node
5. But i am not able to extract only Service1 with data node details(i do not want "test" node details.

Question: Can you please help me to extract data from Service1-with data node only using java code?I am using selenium with java.I need this for one of the script.

```
 Actual response:
    {
"Service1": [
    {
        "data": {
            "status": false,
            "type": "A",
            "order": 1,
            "Version": "v6"
        },
        "test": {
            "ModuleID": "123456",
            "BoxID": "a777",
            "Url": "https://google.com"

        }

    },
    {
       "data": {
            "status": true,
            "type": "B",
            "order": 1,
            "Version": "v2"
        },
        "test": {
            "ModuleID": "123456",
            "BoxID": "a777",
            "Url": "https://google.com"


        }
    }

],
"Service2": {
   "data1": {
            "status": false,
            "type": "c",
            "order": 1,
            "Version": "v6"
        },
        "dashboard": {
            "ModuleID": "123456",
            "BoxID": "a777",
            "Url": "https://google.com"

        }
}
}

Expected data :
[
  {
    "status": false,
    "type": "A",
    "order": 1,
    "Version": "v6"
   },
  {
   "status": true,
   "type": "B",
   "order": 1,
   "Version": "v2"
  }
  ]
```

Comment: Do you want to  read  data from your JSON file and get values of Service1 collection ?

Comment: yes, i want values of Service1 collection with data node only .IN Service1 collection there are two nodes one is "data" another is "test".I want Service1 with data node details.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine I am getting the response in my java code (using eclipse)  .I want to read the data from  code not from any file.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine i need one more help i have response like:{
 "box": {
  "data1": false,
  "data2": false,
  "v3": false,
  "data4": "v4"
  
 },
 "food": {
  "servicedata": {
   "name": "abc",
   "title": "ak",
   "caption": "abc",
   "new": {
    "info": "test"
   },
   "imageUrl": "https://google.com"
  },
  "url": "https://google.com"
  
 }
}      i want food-->Servicedata-->title  , i am using the same code but error :org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray is coming

Comment: solved using same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON simple library](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm) ,it is library used to read/write/parse data in JSON file.In this example i read data from JSON file not a JSON content directly.

```
 private void findData() {

   ArrayList<String> dataArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

try {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/json/Services.json");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    Object obj = parser.parse(reader);
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

    JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Service1");
    Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = msg.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject jsonObjectData = iterator.next();
        JSONObject dataObject = (JSONObject) jsonObjectData.get("data");
        System.out.println(dataObject); 
        //Extract values 
  dataObject.values().stream().forEach(value->{
                    System.out.println(value);
     dataArrayList.add(value.toString());

                });
    }

} catch (IOException | org.json.simple.parser.ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CorporationRegistrationFormController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

}
```

If you need read JSON content from your code just replace the reader with your content like this :  `Object obj = parser.parse("JSON content");`

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddineThanks i am able to get the data node.But is it possible to get all data node of Service1 in a single array format like i have mentioned in expected array.Because now i want to extract the values from the filtered data nodes like type, order,url.

Comment: You can create an ArrayList and add your values into this array.

Comment: I have integrated same code getting o/p as objects are : "{"status":false,"type":"A","order":"1","url":1}
objects are : {"status":false,"type":"B","order":"2","url":1}
objects are : {"status":false,"type":"A","order":"3","url":1}....what should I make the changes to get all result in single array in the above solution?So that i extract the value like status, order, url for each data node?Can u plz help.

Comment: But each data has different values ,do you want a single array contains all values of all data like this : false,A,1,v6,true,B,..... ?

Comment: @akhouri i edited my answer according to your needs (all values in same array).

Comment: Thank you so much it helped a lot.My issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 2):

Fetching the required data is based on the api response. But in the result of the fetched data you can convert it as you want in java as:

Main theme:

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject("json data");//replace json data with your given json data
JSONArray service1 = response.getJSONArray("Service1");
JSONObject firstObjectInService1 = service1.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject secondObjectInService1 = service1.getJSONObject(1);
JSONObject dataInFirstObject = firstObjectInService1.getJSONObject("data");
JSONObject dataInSecondObject = secondObjectInService1.getJSONObject("data");
```

Full code snippet:

```
import org.json.*;
public class JsonParsing {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonData = "{\n" +
            "\"Service1\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"data\": {\n" +
            "            \"status\": false,\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"A\",\n" +
            "            \"order\": 1,\n" +
            "            \"Version\": \"v6\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"test\": {\n" +
            "            \"ModuleID\": \"123456\",\n" +
            "            \"BoxID\": \"a777\",\n" +
            "            \"Url\": \"https://google.com\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "       \"data\": {\n" +
            "            \"status\": true,\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"B\",\n" +
            "            \"order\": 1,\n" +
            "            \"Version\": \"v2\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"test\": {\n" +
            "            \"ModuleID\": \"123456\",\n" +
            "            \"BoxID\": \"a777\",\n" +
            "            \"Url\": \"https://google.com\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "],\n" +
            "\"Service2\": {\n" +
            "   \"data1\": {\n" +
            "            \"status\": false,\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"c\",\n" +
            "            \"order\": 1,\n" +
            "            \"Version\": \"v6\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"dashboard\": {\n" +
            "            \"ModuleID\": \"123456\",\n" +
            "            \"BoxID\": \"a777\",\n" +
            "            \"Url\": \"https://google.com\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "}";
    System.out.println(jsonData);

    try {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(jsonData);//replace json data with your given json data
        JSONArray service1 = response.getJSONArray("Service1");
        JSONObject firstObjectInService1 = service1.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject secondObjectInService1 = service1.getJSONObject(1);
        JSONObject dataInFirstObject = firstObjectInService1.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONObject dataInSecondObject = secondObjectInService1.getJSONObject("data");
        System.out.println(dataInFirstObject);
        System.out.println(dataInSecondObject);
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        //do what you want
    }
}
}
```

so finally in dataInFirstObject we have:

```
{
   "status": false,
   "type": "A",
   "order": 1,
   "Version": "v6" 
}
```

and dataInSecondObject we have:

```
{
    "status": true, 
    "type": "B",
    "order": 1,
    "Version": "v2"
}
```

Comment: hope this will helps you...!

Comment: i have integrated above code but getting error:The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined -->remove argument to match JSONOBject() in the first line.

Comment: have you tried to insert json data in the JSONObject() constructor, it worked for me.

Comment: In order to use JSONObject , you need to import org.json.*; download the json.jar file and import it into your project then this error will be disappeared.

Comment: you can find the json.jar file to download in the following link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm